# jenkins job not waiting defined time

Tags: bash, shell-script, jenkins

i have a jenkins job that is executing a shell, i want it to wait , if  a particular condition is not as per desired state,, but the job executes with 22 sec, where as i have asked it to wait for 30 sec, as the condition is currently not in desired state,,

```
#!/bin/bash
container_name=$(helm install "$USER"-0.1.0.tgz | grep -A2  "v1/Pod(related)" | awk 'NR>2' | awk '{ print $1 }')
container_status=$(kubectl get pod "$container_name" | grep "$container_name" | awk '{ print $3 }')
count=0
if  [ "$container_status" != "Running" ]
   then 
      sleep 10
      count+=1
      if  [ $count -eq 3 ]
        then
          break
      fi          
   else 
      echo "Container is Ready!!"
fi
```

Comment: You have put a sleep of 10 seconds in. This is not 30 seconds?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you want to make that:

```
#!/bin/bash

while [ "$container_status" != "Running" ] ; do
    ...
done
```

because currently you will only go through that code once (and thus the **count** will never reach three anyway).

If you want to detect when something is “ready” you could do worse than use the old trick of reading from a named pipe, and have a separate (sub)process write to the pipe when it's ready.